# C - pstree equivalent

Tags: c, pstree

In BASH there is a pstree command which 'draws' a tree of processes. I am wondering what is the similar function in C programming language?

A simple example would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want that functionality why not just call pstree?

Comment: It's open source, I'm sure you can find it and read how it does it directly.

Comment: @user1926550: simply asking "Can I do X in language Y" is not enough of a question for SO.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  Do you want to draw a tree of something?  Do you want to output information about processes?  Or both?  For the source to pstree, try here for example: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/raring/psmisc

Answer (score 2):

There is no such 'function' in C. But you can easily program something that creates something alike, using `execl()`/`system()` calls to `ps`, or by reading the /proc file system (on linux).

From there, you can get the children list of every process, and for each process of this list get their children etc.. starting from process 1 `init`.

otherwise,

```
int main() {
    system('pstree');
    return 0;
}
```

would work :-)

If you want to reimplement it, you'd better follow Carl Norum's advice to *Use The Source, Luke*!

Comment: ... if you are on a platform on which these system calls apply. If not you will have to use the equivalent system calls for your platform.

Comment: there is no system calls that handle process introspection. I'm sure there is some libraries that handle this we can find on google, but that would'nt be posix. The only standard way to do this, would be the ways I've given in my answer. (though /proc is not standard)